# ClientDetailsService java config outside AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter

Tags: java, spring, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to group all environment-specific beans and such in a couple classes and I'm having a problem with ClientDetailsService in a OAuth2-type app.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
protected static class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

  @Autowired
  private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

  ...

  @Autowired
  private ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService;

  ...

  @Override
  public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
      clients.withClientDetails( clientDetailsService );
  }
}
```

Then I have a separate configuration class like so:

```
@Configuration
@Profile(value={"default"})
public class DevConfiguration {

  ...

  @Bean
  public ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService() {
    return new InMemoryClientDetailsService();
  }

  @Bean
  public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    return new InMemoryUserDetails();
  }

  ...

}
```

I'll then have a `ProductionConfiguration` class using JDBC implementations  and such for all those services. The idea is that `AuthorizationServerConfiguration` has a lot of stuff that apply to all environments (token enhancers, endpoints configuration, etc.) so I'd like to avoid copy/pasting all that code.

The problem is my `public ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService()` isn't being called and the `@Autowired clientDetailsService` in `AuthorizationServerConfiguration` seems to be proxied like it did not find code creating an instance of `ClientDetailsService`.
When it's time for the application to load client details by id, I end up with a `StackOverflowError` (guessing the proxy is calling itself).

I can see other @Bean being instantiated from `DevConfiguration` (like `UserDetailsService`), so it's taking that class into consideration when configuring the app for sure. I'd very much like to avoid using qualifiers as well.

What am I doing wrong?
What's the best way to "externalize" datastores and such from `AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter` and the like?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My `AuthorizationServerConfiguration` was actually inside another `@Configuration` class. 
Turned out that moving `AuthorizationServerConfiguration` to its own file solved the problem.